# error Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Tags: codeigniter

I get the following error from the code below:

> Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

```
 $cari = $this->db->query("select sum( biaya )
    FROM bahanbenang
    WHERE id_benang
    IN ($benang) ");
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: `$benang` is not a string.  You can't use it inside a string if it's not a string.  What is `$benang`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always go like this

```
$this->db->select('sum( biaya )')
                ->from('bahanbenang')
                ->where('seen', 0)
                ->where_in('id_benang',$benang);
return $data->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

You run a query but must retrieve its results

```
$query = $this->db->query("select sum( biaya )
FROM bahanbenang
WHERE id_benang
IN ($benang) "); 

$cari = $query->result();  //this will return an array of objects. Each object is a row from the query
```

Other results methods [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).